# How to run debug in VS Code so that it would launch Chrome in debug mode with paused .js scripts on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

Summary:
I got VS Code.
I got empty HTML template file in which i learn how to write js scripts.
VS Code has debugger, which can launch my file in Chrome for debugging (theoretically).
I set up breakpoints in file.

I can make debugger launch Chrome and open HTML file, but Chrome doesn't stop on breakpoints and runs whole script.

I cant pause scripts from VS Code. Unless i pause script from Chrome dev tools manually.

Question:
How to run debug in VS Code so that it would launch Chrome in debug mode with paused .js scripts on HTML page?

i mean, i really dont use something exotic like external scripts or environments or other stuff.
Its just a plain HTML template file, with 5-30 lines of .js script code in it. Nothing else. I would expect something so basic would be able to work "from the box" with a push of a button. But its not.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time on the same issue. VSCode's built in debugger does not work right with JS. After Chrome debugger extension was deprecated, JavaScript breakpoints show unbound. You should not have to run any commands to do JS debugging with a  launch.json file. I was able to get a workaround by adding debugging; before your first JS breakpoint. Once this gets hit, any following breakpoints will get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly, VSCode started using breakpoints properly now. Maybe there was some hotfix or something.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible:

From the VSCode docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging

> The simplest way to debug a webpage is through the Debug: Open Link command found in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). When you run this command, you'll be prompted for a URL to open, and the debugger will be attached.

Comment: I`ve seen this link, but i didn't noticed debugger command since its grey on grey and very small font.

Do i have to use debugger command everytime in code to make use of this feature? And it seems i need to start script after that for it to reach breakpoint.
Looks a bit weird, why breakpoints are not used without those extra actions from me? Its good that it at least works this way, though.